# fatal error allowed memory size in php page

Tags: php, php5, apache-2.2

m getting following error while executing following url

***URL***

> http://vcoders.in/Scraping/test/readData.php

***Error***

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of
>   50331648 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 71 bytes) in in
>   /home/vcodec9s/public_html/Scraping/test/simple_html_dom.php
>   on line 827

Answer (score 1):

If the script is actually running out of memory, you may need to increase PHP's allotted amount. The setting for max memory is in the php.ini file -- look for memory_limit. You'll have to restart apache (or whatever web server you're using).

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit

Comment: Yep.  Give it more memory, and maybe try and figure out why your script is so memory-hungry.  On the other hand, remember that it's PHP, and it's never gonna be that light on memory usage.